# std::function and default function arguments

Tags: c++, default-arguments

Here is simple example of using `std::function`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//A function that sums two numbers.
//Arguments having default values.
void SumOfTwoNumbers(int a = 42, int b = 42)
{
    std::cout << "Sum of two numbers :: " << a + b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int, int)> testFunc = SumOfTwoNumbers;

    SumOfTwoNumbers();          //Works
    testFunc();                 //Compile time error          
    testFunc(40, 40);           //Works

    return 0;
}
```

In the main function, there are three function calls. The first one and the last one works. Whereas the second call `testFunc()` without any arguments gives compile time error.

Shouldn't it consider the default arguments and execute successfully?

Comment: You would [need a different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22920596/1460794) `std::function` object to call without arguments.

Comment: Use of default arguments like that effectively creates 3 overloaded methods: `void SumOfTwoNumbers()`, `void SumOfTwoNumbers(int)` and `void SumOfTwoNumbers(int, int)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the default values for function arguments are not part of the function signature. They are evaluated at the call site only.

You could use a lambda but then you'd need to redefine the default values:

```cpp
auto testFunc = [](int a = 42, int b = 42) { SumOfTwoNumbers(a, b); };
```

... and storing such a lambda in a `std::function` would again result in the same problem since the signature of the lambda is also `void(int, int)`.

---

You *could* however define your own wrapper functor (instead of using `std::function`) that has *multiple* `operator()` overloads:

```cpp
struct {
    void operator()() { SumOfTwoNumbers(42, 42); } 
    void operator()(int a) { SumOfTwoNumbers(a, 42); } 
    void operator()(int a, int b) { SumOfTwoNumbers(a, b); } 
} testFunc;
```